# Why the $get method isn't being called?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to write a provider in angular but I can't figure why the $get method isn't being called.

I know what it is but I don't know **when** it's being called by angular, is it when the provider is injected? what do I need to return from there? can anyone make a simple example that demonstrate it?

I tried the AngularJS [examples](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers) but for the life of me I'm getting the same results.

```
var RoutingProvider = (function () {
    function RoutingProvider() {
        this.$get = function ($injector) {
            console.log("do something");

            return new RoutingProvider();
        };
        this.$get.$inject = ['$injector'];
    }
    RoutingProvider.prototype.register = function (routes) {
        console.log(routes);
    };
    return RoutingProvider;
})();
```

**EDIT:**

Here is the example provided by angular documentation.

```
function UnicornLauncher(apiToken, useTinfoilShielding) {
    this.launchedCount = 0;
    this.launch = function() {
      this.launchedCount++;
    }
}

bootstrap.provider('unicornLauncher', function UnicornLauncherProvider() {
    var useTinfoilShielding = false;

    this.useTinfoilShielding = function(value) {
      useTinfoilShielding = !!value;
    };

    this.$get = ["apiToken", function unicornLauncherFactory(apiToken) {
        console.log("foo");
      // let's assume that the UnicornLauncher constructor was also changed to
      // accept and use the useTinfoilShielding argument
      return new UnicornLauncher(apiToken, useTinfoilShielding);
    }];
});

bootstrap.config(["unicornLauncherProvider", function(unicornLauncherProvider) {
    unicornLauncherProvider.useTinfoilShielding(true);
}]);
```

Here is the [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/PfDZRq) I made which demonstrates it.

Again, I can't see the printed message coming from the $get function.

Comment: Show your code?  It might help.

Comment: Can you post the code you've tried that isn't behaving as you expect?

Comment: Well my code is written in TypeScript and I already posted an issue about it in SO but no one replied, I'll try to convert it to JavaScript. Updated my post with the original issue.

Comment: @Miraage, this is the output made by the TypeScript compiler and while I might not understand what I'm writing I do know what I need to achieve. tell me that I don't understand what I'm writing isn't helpful at all but thank you for nothing.

Comment: Downvoter, at least tell me why are you downvoting me when I'm simply asking for help?

Comment: what do you expect to be calling $get?

Comment: Well, when injecting the provider, I think.

Comment: I'm pretty new to angular so I might missing something, I've put the time reading the docs but again I'm just cannot see one example that shows me when it's called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from Angular channel over irc by Foxandxss, here is what he said.

> there is two different injection places services, controllers,
>   directives, run oh, and filters there you can inject services but NOT
>   providers then, you have another injection place, providers and config
>   functions there you can only inject constant and providers so a
>   provider has two parts the "provider part, which is configuration" and
>   the "factory" inside it which is the $get if you inject your provider
>   in another provider or config you inject the configuration part and
>   you have to append the Provider on the name so when you inject
>   "unicornLauncher" into config you should put "unicornLauncherProvider"
>   that will inject the configuration part and not the $get if you go to
>   a controller and you inject unicornLauncher it will inject the factory
>   inside it (AKA the $get) you won't be able to access
>   "usetinfoilshielding" inside it because that is part of the provider
>   and not the factory ($get) inside so basically a provider is two parts
>   and you use one or the other you can't use both